# button_to path routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm having trouble routing a button so that it calls an action in a controller. To be more specific, I have this line

```
delete 'destroy/:id', to: 'users#admin_destroy'
```

in my route file, and this line

```
%= button_to 'Destroy', destroy_path(user), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
```

in a view.

The problem is that the page keeps treating destroy_path as a method, and I'm at a loss for what the proper syntax should be. What am I misunderstanding?

Additionally, I originally tried to get this work as link_to, but I learned that that should be reserved for GET requests. However, I don't like how button_to looks, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this as a GET so that link_to can be used instead.

Comment: An exact error message would be helpful.  How are you populating `user` (should it be `@user`)?  Your routes.rb line of code has no mention of a url_helper path, so I'm not sure if you can use `destroy_path` without associating it with a route.  What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: And you should not be using link_to/GET for an action that could alter the database.  Without getting too much into the security implications, or how bots search a website, or idempotent actions, it is really not recommended and you will be better prepared to learn how to do this with a correct HTTP verb and change the look of the button with css.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I call this 
`<%= render :partial => 'users/user', :collection => users %`
in _user_list.html.erb (the original destroy_path line is in _user.html.erb).

I'd rather not list the entirety of rake routes, since it's rather large, but what I'm saying is that I think destroy_path is the wrong thing to link to the destroy route--I just don't know what the right one is. Currently, the page thinks destroy_path is a method and doesn't know how to define it (since it's not actually a method, I just guessed at the route syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will completely solve your problem, but... You can custom define a path like so:

in `config/routes.rb`

```
delete 'destroy/:id', to: 'users#admin_destroy', as: :destroy
```

This will allow you to use `destroy_path` in your application, and have it route to your users controller with the admin_destroy function.

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: Thanks--this seems to work, once I add `method: :delete` to my original view line as well. I guess doing it this way makes it clearer that I'm just redirecting to a controller and running the appropriate HTTP method, which I'm more used to doing from php. I'm a lit curious as to why I need the `as: :destroy` though--doesn't that defeat the purpose of having routing at well? If I'm already identifying the button_to as delete, and doing so in a view for the user controller, why do I need to additionally define `destroy_path`? Is there some predefined path I'm not using?

Comment: So Rails big thing is Convention over Configuration.  So the idea is that when you do `resources models` in your routes, it sets up most all of your CRUD paths for you and names them appropriately (I don't think anyone of them is the destroy_path).  However, if you decide to create a custom route, as you have done, then rails doesn't create a url helper route because it doesn't know what to name it, so you have to explicitly name it yourself with the `as:` declaration.